# Spring Batch Write Header

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a spring-batch file that extracts data from a database and writes it to a .CSV file.

I would like to add the names of the columns that are extracted as the headers of the file without hard coding them on the file.

Is possible to write the header when I get the results or is there another solution?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some of the code you have thus far? Also what does this have to do with java?

Comment: Because i use java to access the database. I will post some code

Answer (score 0):

```
fileItemWriter.setHeaderCallback(new FlatFileHeaderCallback() {
            public void writeHeader(Writer writer) throws IOException {
                writer.write(Arrays.toString(names));
            }
        });
```

[names] can be fetched using reflections from the domain class you created for the column names to be used by rowMapper, something like below :

```
private String[] reflectFields() throws ClassNotFoundException { 
        Class job = Class.forName("DomainClassName");
        Field[] fields = FieldUtils.getAllFields(job);
        names = new String[fields.length];
        for(int i=0; i<fields.length; i++){
            names[i] = fields[i].getName(); 
        }
        return names;
    }
```